# "LIKE" in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a simple mysql search form that searches between two dates. 
This query working perfect:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE  dateStarted like '%$checkin%' 
AND dateEnded like '%$checkout%'";
```

But with

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE  dateStarted = $checkin 
AND dateEnded = $checkout";
```

There is no any result? What is difference between two sql?

Edit:

```
$checkin and $checkout are date (16-07-2010)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) What datatype you use for dateStarted?
2) What's contents of $checkin and $checkout variables?

Comment: $checkin and $checkout are date (16-07-2010)

Comment: You should write the date in the right format: YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: You could have avoided the issue by using parameterized query, which would make sure the values are inserted into the query properly. Check out PDO! It's so worth it! And more secure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $checkin and $checkout are date
>   (16-07-2010)

Try putting quotes in your query:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE  dateStarted = '$checkin'
         AND dateEnded = '$checkout'";
```

Answer (score 2):

One matches the value of the variable $checkin, the other matches anything *containing* the value of the variable $checkin.

So if $checkin is foo, then the first will match "foo" or "something foosomething" while the second will match only "foo".

Answer (score -2):

"like" is for text and "=" for numbers and so on

Comment: Not the case at all. Learn MySQL before making such comments.

Comment: i have just repeated the words of my teacher... its not only about mysql its about the hole think like DB. Yes you can search numbers with "like" but it isn't clear...